# how to move an inbound email message from one case to another

Tags: case, email2case

We received an email from a customer that was attached to the wrong case (there was an incorrect case ref in the body of the email).
Is there a way of moving the email record to the correct case?

Comment: Can you please try querying the EmailMessage object with parentId = <id_of_old_case> and then update the parentId on that record with ID of the new case?

Comment: I tried using the Data order but its not possible to update the ParentID field (it is not selectable when mapping)

Comment: looks like the only option is to make a copy (except the parentId) and then insert a new record with new parentId and delete the previous record?

Comment: why not use your email client, copy paste the subject/body of the incorrectly parented email into the Compose new Email window, edit out the thread Id in both subject and body, replacing with the thread id for the desired destination case, and then send the email to your support@mycompany.com email address?

Comment: What tool you use to add email into cases as I noticed here that you mentioned you attached email to the wrong case?